# What happens if Stanley falls while remembering the warehouse?

Tags: the-stanley-parable-ultra-deluxe

In The Stanley Parable: Ultra Deluxe:

> After [collecting 6 Stanley figurines](https://nintendosmash.com/the-stanley-parable-ultra-deluxe-all-figurine-collectibles/), the Narrator takes you back to the Memory Zone to revisit the places you found the figures. One of these is [on top of the planks in the warehouse](https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxYFpgOiJs3z5Kvsx5px99T63-H3nn3W0p). Normally falling in the warehouse leads to [an ending where Stanley dies](https://youtu.be/-8VTSt6KiUg). What happens if you try to walk off the ledge while revisiting the warehouse in the Memory Zone?

I'd test this myself, but there doesn't seem to be a way to return there once you've left.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: No, you cannot.

> When visiting the warehouse setup in the memory zone, the planks were surrounded by invisible walls. It is designed in a way that you cannot fall onto the floor even if you want to.

Comment: Just to add validity, I also tried this and got the same result.